# Check and find type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

The question is:

> Give a type declaration of  `(f True) (f 1)` such that it is
>   well-typed or explain why it cannot exist.

Kindly please help me as I am unable to understand how to define type declaration. Thank you.

Comment: Is the body of `f` given?

Comment: @DavidYoung No. I have just this expression and it asks me to find its type.

Comment: @DavidYoung I have edited my question. It is the exact question in that paper.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would infer the type of `f` from your expression. Note that I'm not presenting how GHC works but how my "brain type checker" works.

`f True` is applied to a value, which means that the `f` on the left has type `f True :: a -> b`, so `f :: Bool -> a -> b`.

On the right, we have `f 1`, which means that on the right `f :: (Num a) => a -> b`, this is when my internal type checker starts to complain, because from the application of `f` on the left, I see that `f` can be applied to `Bool`, and on the right that it can be applied to a number, but `Bool` is not an instance of the `Num` class.

However this still type checks if there is no constraint on the first argument, so we have `f :: a -> b` and… we can't really say anything else I think. (Because `b` can be any type, it is perfectly possible that `b` is actually a `c -> d`, so we can obtain a new function from applying `f` partially.)

Note though that even if this type checks (you can check it in GHCi), it is very unlikely that `f` as a meaningful definition, in fact the only function it can represent that is not `undefined` is `const` I think (but correct if I'm wrong). You can say that because there is no constraint on the type of the first argument which is rather strange…

---

According to your comment `f :: a -> b -> Bool` (I was trying to have the most general type possible from the information given by the expression you typed, this is my result is a bit more general.)

There is only one way to define such a function without using `undefined`, it has to be a function that discards both its argument and give a constant. Because there is no way `f` can be defined for any type immaginable. So the definition of `f` is something like:

```
f _ _ = True
```

When you apply `f True` to `f 1`, you apply `f True :: b -> Bool` to a function `f 1 :: b -> Bool`, this is well typed because `b` is a type variable, it can be anything, in particular it is perfectly fine for `b` to be a `c -> Bool`, and in that case, the type of `f True` is in fact `f True :: (c -> Bool) -> Bool`. Is it clearer?

Comment: Actually the answer is f :: a -> b -> Bool and says it is well typed but i don't understand how they conclude this result.

Comment: also there are brackets on both, so what i understand is (f Bool) result is applied to (f 1) result, and I don't understand how it is well typed.

Comment: Ok this looks like some sort of constant function, I'll edit my answer to explain the case where `f` is `const` or some function that discards its result.

Comment: Thank you for this one. But im still confused how to know the type of this expression. Here I have type so i can conclude how it comes, but what to do when I have only expression.

Comment: Well you can't really say much more than what I said at first with just the expression. If you had the result of it then it would have been possible to infer the right type and the definition.

Comment: actually it is a question in one of my past paper exams and im preparing for that. Im still confused if this kind of question appears again in exam, how i gonna answer that.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed I think something is wrong with the question. It doesn't make sense that they would give `f :: a -> b -> Bool` as an answer because there is no reason the result type is required to be `Bool`. It could be *any* type (consider `f :: a -> b -> Char; f _ _ = 'a'`. That allows the expression to type check as well). You might consider asking your teacher about this one. There might have been a mistake.

Comment: @villou24 I have edited my question. It is the exact question in that paper.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed Then yes, as suggested by David Young it looks like a mistake in the question, or at least a lack of information.

Comment: @villou24 I hope that I won't come around questions like this during exam.

Comment: @WaqarAhmed My best advice is to bring this to the teacher's attention and see what they say.

Comment: the more general definition is `f :: a->b->c ; f _ _ = undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the body of f, you can type ":t f" in GHCI (the haskell interpreter) to get its type.

If all you know about f is that (f True) (f 1) compiles, then f could be any constant function of 2 variables, like `\x y -> 2  :: a -> b -> Int`, or `\x y = "foo" :: a -> b -> String` or even `\x y -> readFile "any.txt" :: a -> b -> IO (String)`.

Comment: for `> :t f` to work, you'd have to have `f` defined first. But the OP states they aren't given the definition, only the expression.